# Asp.Net MVC 5 + Bootstrap. How make inputs fit screen width?

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. I want my textboxes with same size of my buttons below. I already tried change a lot in the cshtml but without success.

[image]

Below my cshtml file:

```
@model SomeModel.Models.LoginViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Entrar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 visible-sm visible-xs">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Ainda Não Tenho Conta</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 visible-sm visible-xs">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Esqueci Meu Usuário Ou Senha</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register") if you don't have a local account.
                </p>
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The default _site.css_ defines a rule to limit the width. I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313711/asp-net-mvc-how-to-increase-the-width-of-an-inputfield-with-html-editorfor/30332474#30332474)

Comment: You're right. I never would find this alone. Thank you :). PS: Post this as answer.

Comment: I found this with Chrome's dev tools. I inspected the element and it showed what css rules were attached and which files those rules were defined. But yeah, it stumped me for a while too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default MVC5 template has a css rule in *Site.css*:

```
input, select, textarea { max-width: 280px; }
```

I usually remove this rule.

It causes problems with Bootstrap v3 input group where the input box does not extend to its container's width.