# How increase length of input form in EditorFor in ASP.MVC bootstrap template?

Tags: css, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I use bootstrap template on ASP.MVC (but it's minor fact). I have this code on View:

```
   <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.udk_number, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.udk_number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.udk_number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

But @Html.EditorFor have limited length. How i can increase length of this input?

Similar problem i have and with TextArea:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="annotation_ru">Аннотация(RU)</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <textarea class=form-control id="annotation_ru" name="annotation_ru" rows="3" cols="100"></textarea>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="annotation_ru" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I can stretch this area only to the same length as that of the input in example above.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958361/asp-net-mvc-5-bootstrap-how-make-inputs-fit-screen-width/30958451#30958451

Comment: `@Html.EditorFor` does not have any lengths at all. Your css does.

Answer (score 0):

Style your `<input>` fields using CSS. I usually make them 100% wide so that they are nice and responsive.

```
input[type=text],
textarea {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: yes, i know that my input fiels using CSS. But i don't find class, who may change width of input! I try change form-horizontal, form-group and form-control. Not working.